# how to configure my application with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new with spring security I tried  to read and there is alot of information and I don't know if I am in the right direction.
I have html file that the html element create with JS
lets assume that I have two input fields with ID ( html input fields )

```
      emailInput and passwordInput
```

and button with ID ( html button )

```
      loginLabel
```

I added the configuration to pring-security-config

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

  </beans>
```

I added to web.xml

```
 filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

I created Servlet Filer

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

}

How i connect between the fields in the input ( the element are not from tag ) to the SecurityConfig  ?

Do I need to create from element or I can do it without it ?

Do I need to create JSP file or is it ok to use html files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Step 1**: Enable HTTP security.
2. **Step 2**: Turn on form login.
3. **Step 3**: Set the names of the username and password parameters expected in the login request.

Sample below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .formLogin()
        .usernameParameter("emailInput")
        .passwordParameter("passwordInput");
  }
}
```

Comment: Whar did you mean in step 1 and 2?how i can enable  http secuirty and enable form login

Comment: one more thing if the parameters is not from is it ok to use .formLogin or I need to change my UI to form ?

Comment: I didn't understand the question.  `.formLogin()` tells Spring Security that authentication would be performed via an HTML form.  As long as the authentication request is submitted as a regular HTTP request, using `.formLogin()` will work.  It won't matter if you don't have a static form in the HTML and the form parameters are generated dynamically.  You will simply need to make sure that the username and password are submitted as normal HTTP parameters (`[name]=[value]`) pairs.